# Nginx config static website show 404 Not found

Tags: http, nginx, https, webserver

I'm config a static website in nginx,but show 404 notfound on browser

nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

nginx configuration：

```
upstream client {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
upstream admin {
        server 127.0.0.1:8090;
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name mp.example.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/certificate/mp.example.com/1_mp.example.com_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/certificate/mp.example.com/2_mp.example.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 4m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!DHE;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://client;
                #Proxy Settings
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        }
        location /admin {
                proxy_pass http://admin;
                #Proxy Settings
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        }

        location /zp {
                root    /root/admin_ui/1.1.0;
                index   index.html;
        }

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                expires 90d;
                alias /root/www/assets/;
        }

}
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name mp.example.com;
        location / {
                rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
        }

}
```

Broswer screehshots:

[image: access website]

my static website path:

[image: my static website path]

I want input https://xx.xxxx.com/zp show my website

I think https configuration's problem, but i not sure

Comment: Please copy & paste configuration text when possible. Screenshots of text are not searchable and hard to read for some people. Also try to reproduce a minimal example of the problem instead of making people read through test rest of the irrelevant configuration.
Most importantly: if you need to redact info like domain names, please use example.com as this name is reserved for this purpose. You may need to add subdomains as needed to keep the configuration as relevant as possible.

Comment: You could enable logs it your config. It should gives you some details about this issue:
 ```access_log /var/log/nginx/mp.example.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mp.example.com_error.log;```